# Buying high-quality papers for use with large format fine art ink jet printers?

Tags: printing, ink-jet, large-format, paper

I'm at a loss as to where I can buy nice, high-quality ink jet papers (Hahnemühle, Museo DFA, Breathing Color, Ilford, etc.) at a local store (rather than on the internet.) There are a couple local camera shops, like Mikes Camera and a couple film development shops that sell fine art ink jet papers, however they tend to have a very limited selection.

In particular, actual Hahnemühle (outside of the two or three types of Canon Fine Art papers that are actually made by Hahnemühle), Museo Digital Fine Art papers, Breathing Color (a brand that I found recently that has some very nice 100% cotton papers and canvas), Ilford (most shops have ilford film development papers, but not much in the way of ink jet printing paper), etc. seems fairly rare. Finding actual packs of paper directly from any of these brands seems almost impossible, but I'm hoping I just don't know of the proper store names to go looking for it at.

Are there any common stores where I can find high quality, fine art papers from the brands listed above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adorama carries many of these papers, including hahnemuhle. so does B&H.

Comment: I do know that...honestly, the original question was really about local stores, not online stores. I was wondering if there was some known chain of art or photography supply stores that stocked these papers, so I could just run down to one and pick stuff up as needed, rather than having to order and wait. Guess that wasn't very clear.

Comment: every reasonably size metro area probably has a camera shop that caters to the local pros, but they're rarely chains, so you have to find them. That'd be your best shot for finding a supply like that. It might take some exploring; I'd say the easiest way to get a list of candidates is to look for the shops that sell medium format gear. They'd be likely ones to also carry the higher end papers and other pro-oriented products. If not, they'll likely know who does...

Comment: Well, few local stores around me actually carry any decent papers. I finally just went with online stores, including Adorama, B&H, and Amazon. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind ordering from a Canadian store, you can find most of these, if not all, at [Vistek](http://www.vistek.ca/) and they do ship to the United States.

Comment: Thanks for the link. They seem to have everything there...lots of Canon lenses, including hte MP-E 65mm Macro (I've never seen that anywhere.) It doesn't seem to stock the Museo or Breathing Color papers, but it does have Hahnemuhle and Ilford stuff. I generally prefer Hahnemuhle anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I usually find a lot of what I want there and they're pretty convenient for me (maybe too convenient). Though, in my experience, they can be a little more expensive, but they're often the only source I have for some things.

Answer (score 1):

Check high-end art supply stores as well as camera stores.

I'm going on my experience here in Vancouver: the most reliable selection is actually [Opus](http://opusframing.com/).  They do online ordering, but I don't know their shipping situation, so I mention it more for the general idea to check art stores.

The good local camera stores (there are a couple, we're pretty spoiled compared to a lot of places) have a decent selection, but not as much large paper, and not as much variety of brands and surface treatments.  They're happy to order in anything you want, but Opus carries a larger stock more regularly.

Comment: Thanks for the link. They seem to have a couple of the Museo papers. Guess that stuff is pretty rare. Here in Colorado we seem to be a little gimped when it comes to good digital photography outlets...there just isn't a very good selection of materials. Which is odd, since we are such a hot spot for nature and landscape photography...